# $M^{\perp}$ in $l^2$ space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $M= \{ x \in l^2 : x_{2n} =  0 \ \ \forall n\in \mathbb{N} \}$, then find $M^{\perp}$.

My guess is $M^{\perp} = \{ z \in l^2 : z_{2n+1} = 0 \ \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \}$

if $z \in M^{\perp} \iff \langle z,x\rangle = 0 \iff \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}z_{2n+1}\overline{x_{2n+1}} = 0$.
How to proceed further? How do I conclude that $z_{2n+1} = 0 \ \ \forall  n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Hint: assume $z_{2n + 1} \neq 0$ for some $n$. Find $x \in M$ s.t. $\langle z, x \rangle \neq 0$.

Comment: First, do not write "$z \in M^{\perp} \iff <z,x> = 0$" but $z \in M^{\perp} \iff\forall x\in M,\langle z,x\rangle= 0.$ Then, to prove that $M^\perp$ is contained in "your guess" (the reverse inclusion being obvious), no need of a proof by contradiction: if $\forall x\in M,\langle z,x\rangle= 0$ then in particular, for each $n,$ $\langle z,\delta_{2n+1}\rangle= 0.$

Comment: $\langle z, e_i \rangle = z_i$, where $e_i = (\delta_{in})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: will $e_{2n+1}$ do? @mihaild

Comment: Note that the $x$ in your expression is arbitrary element from $M$ so you can in particular choose specific element for each $n$ which will help you show $z_{2n+1} = 0 $.

Comment: Thanks, everyone, I got it.